# How can I connect one docker container to another via the default bridge network?

Tags: docker, networking, redis, python-3.6

I have a python 3.6 app running inside a docker container (linux python3.6 base image), and this app needs to access another container with a redis instance on it. I have both containers running on the default bridge network, and I have configured the first container to point to the second using the second container's IPv4Address:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = redis://172.17.0.3:6379/0
```

According to the tutorials on docker, this is all you need to connect one container to another when they're running on the same host machine(with no firewalls etc). However, I keep getting a [Errno 111] Connection refused when I try to connect to the redis container. I have checked that the ICC is enabled, and my default bridge network looks like this:

```
[
{
    "Name": "bridge",
    "Id": "fda5906e0a6009a5a7dd8839f4d85cdc8de15db34481b7ef15ce66f4343b2f63",
    "Created": "2021-03-24T07:54:17.8315909Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "38beb0863d86dab0f014ef9f1ad85f02efa7fb96520455df6f6ea6b5519f60cc": {
            "Name": "local_redis",
            "EndpointID": "74f510467dba138f10e1662830060a05ee192c368b32844af73eb4e865fc7182",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
            "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "f314393b25019c8c3084b8cf8465284d5a45c2f48c9aa5c411343e6a5f833c62": {
            "Name": "rabbitmq",
            "EndpointID": "a4886c398708d5279a8bf0de9dbd8eadd10dd320120243a2ca8c26e0e0c20e16",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {
        "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
        "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
    },
    "Labels": {}
}
```

]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't use the default bridge network, and don't directly look up the container-private IP addresses.  If you `docker network create` a network, and then `docker run --net ... --name ...` the containers, the `--name`s will be usable as host names.  If you're using Docker Compose, it will do this automatically (the Compose `default` network is a "user-defined bridge network") and [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) has a reasonable overview of the setup there.

Comment: @DavidMaze I got the following error: The container name "/rabbitmq-server" is already in use by container "f314393b25019c8c3084b8cf8465284d5a
45c2f48c9aa5c411343e6a5f833c62". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name. Did you mean list the images instead of the containers? Because this command seems to create containers